# Multi Client Server - receive event goes crazy after client disconnection & async error

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, connection, client

edit

40+ views, and only one is able to help, isn't that question worth the upvote ? ;)

/edit

again I've some issues with socket programming in c#.

I've set up a little server with selfmade console ( richTextBox ) and it's listening for multiple connections.

well everything works fine except that if i close one of the connected clients, the programm will give me an async error and on the console it continuously writes a blank message from the client ( event:ClientReceivedHandler )

so can anyone help me finding the problem ??

my code :

SERVER - Form1.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace GameServer {
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    // ### MAIN
    public bool serverRunning = false;
    public int serverListenPort = 6666;

    static Listener l;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        l = new Listener( serverListenPort );
        l.SocketAccepted += new Listener.SocketAcceptedHandler( l_SocketAccepted );
    }

    void l_SocketAccepted( Socket e ) {
        Client client = new Client( e );
        client.Received += new Client.ClientReceivedHandler( client_Received );
        client.Disconnected += new Client.ClientDisconnectedHandler( client_Disconnected );

        Invoke( ( MethodInvoker )delegate {
            dataGridViewConnections.Rows.Add( client.ID, client.EndPoint.ToString() );
            consoleWrite( DateTime.Now + " - " + client.EndPoint + " connected to server.\n\n", Color.Lime );
        } );
    }

    void client_Received( Client sender, byte[] data ) {
        Invoke( ( MethodInvoker )delegate {
            consoleWrite( DateTime.Now + "-" + sender.EndPoint + " :\n" + Encoding.Default.GetString( data ) + "\n\n", Color.White );;
        } );
    }

    void client_Disconnected( Client sender ) {
        Invoke( ( MethodInvoker )delegate {
            for( int i = 0; i < dataGridViewConnections.Rows.Count; i++ ) {
                if( dataGridViewConnections.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == sender.ID.ToString() ) {
                    dataGridViewConnections.Rows.RemoveAt( i );
                    consoleWrite( DateTime.Now + " - " + sender.EndPoint + " disconnected from server.\n\n", Color.OrangeRed );
                    break;
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        checkBox1.Enabled = false;
        if( !serverRunning ) {
            consoleWrite( DateTime.Now + " " + markerSystem + "start\n", Color.White );
            ServerStart();
            checkBox1.Text = "Stop";
        } else {
            consoleWrite( DateTime.Now + " " + markerSystem + "stop\n", Color.White );
            ServerStop();
            checkBox1.Text = "Start";
        }
        checkBox1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void ServerStart() {
        if( !serverRunning ) {
            consoleWrite( "* Starting server . . .\n", Color.Orange );
            // Start Server
            l.Start();
            serverRunning = true;
            consoleWrite( "* Server started !\n", Color.Lime );
            consoleWrite("Listening on port " + serverListenPort + ".\n\n", Color.White );
        } else {
            consoleWrite( "* ERROR: Server already started !\n\n", Color.Red );
        }
    }

    private void ServerStop() {
        if( serverRunning ) {
            consoleWrite( "* Stopping server . . .\n", Color.Orange );
            // Stop Server
            l.Stop();
            serverRunning = false;
            consoleWrite( "* Server stopped !\n\n", Color.Lime );
        } else {
            consoleWrite( "* ERROR: Server already stopped !\n\n", Color.Red );
        }
    }

    private string markerSystem = "@System -> ";
    private string marker = "-> ";

    private void consoleWrite( string text, Color color ) {
        consoleText.SelectionStart = consoleText.Text.Length;
        consoleText.SelectionLength = 0;
        consoleText.SelectionColor = color;
        consoleText.AppendText( text );
    }
}
}
```

SERVER - Listener.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace GameServer {
    class Listener {
        Socket s;

        public bool Listening {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public int Port {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public  Listener( int port ) {
            Port = port;
            s = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
        }

        public void Start() {
            if( Listening ) {
                return;
            }

            s.Bind( new IPEndPoint( 0, Port ) );
            s.Listen(0);

            s.BeginAccept( callback, null );
            Listening = true;
        }

        public void Stop() {
            if( !Listening ) {
                return;
            }

            s.Close();
            s.Dispose();
            s = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
        }

        void callback( IAsyncResult ar ) {
            try {
                Socket s = this.s.EndAccept( ar );

                if( SocketAccepted != null ) {
                    SocketAccepted( s );
                }

                this.s.BeginAccept( callback, null );
            } catch( Exception ex ) {
                MessageBox.Show( ex.Message );
            }
        }

        public delegate void SocketAcceptedHandler( Socket e );
        public event SocketAcceptedHandler SocketAccepted;
    }
}
```

SERVER - Client.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace GameServer {
    class Client {
        public string ID {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public IPEndPoint EndPoint {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        Socket sck;

        public Client( Socket accepted ) {
            sck = accepted;
            ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            EndPoint = ( IPEndPoint )sck.RemoteEndPoint;
            sck.BeginReceive( new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0, 0, callback, null );
        }

        void callback( IAsyncResult ar ) {
            try {
                sck.EndReceive( ar );

                byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
                int rec = sck.Receive( buf, buf.Length, 0 );

                if( rec < buf.Length ) {
                    Array.Resize<byte>( ref buf, rec );
                }

                if( Received != null ) {
                    Received( this, buf );
                }

                sck.BeginReceive( new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0, 0, callback, null );
            } catch( Exception ex ) {
                MessageBox.Show( ex.Message );
                Close();

                if( Disconnected != null ) {
                    Disconnected( this );
                }
            }
        }

        public void Close() {
            sck.Close();
            sck.Dispose();
        }

        public delegate void ClientReceivedHandler( Client sender, byte[] data );
        public delegate void ClientDisconnectedHandler( Client sender );

        public event ClientReceivedHandler Received;
        public event ClientDisconnectedHandler Disconnected;
    }
}
```

CLIENT - Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace GameClient {
    public partial class Form1:Form {
        Socket sck;

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            sck = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
            sck.Connect( "127.0.0.1", 6666 );
        }

        private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            int s = sck.Send( Encoding.Default.GetBytes( textBox1.Text ) );

            if( s > 0 ) {
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            sck.Close();
            sck.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

i would be really really glad to make this server stable so i can start implementing multiplayer game server logics :D

thanks everyone who can help me out.

P.S. If anyone needs to see the problem in action, i can upload the VS project files or the .exe files of server and client.

**UPDATE :**

the first problem ( async error ) appears in the Listener.cs file in the try-catch. the messagebox in the catch section gives this text :

"IAsyncResult object was not returned from the corresponding asynchronous method. parameter : asyncResult"

this comes when the "ServerStop()" method is called.

the second problem is anywhere in the client_Received() method in the SERVER-Form1.cs.

it seems that it continuously receives blank data, so it outputs a blank message in the console/richTextBox

I'm not familiar with the socket-logic in c#, so i can't figure out where in the code the locig-error happens.

hope that anyone has found it.

**EDIT :**

project files in zip file
http://ace-acid.no-ip.org/GameServer/

(c)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: it's deconstructive and the "C#" is just that everyone can see it is a c# question. go seee if u can catch some misspelling, but if u are hunting that kind of error you should better go with other forums.

Comment: @Ace I've built the solution and added the controls but I don't see any problems yet. May you please provide the steps that lead to output the problem? :)

Comment: my englisch is not the best. what exactly do you want to know ? did you see my update ?

Comment: @Ace Oh yes, Sorry I've got it now. Thank you for providing the information. I've also received the error when I clicked on Stop. I'll try my best to solve this :)

Comment: @Ace: I've been on this "forum" three years longer than you have. I know, for instance, that the [c#] tag is much more helpful in making people know it's a C# question than messing up your title is. The title should be the title, and the tags should be the tags. Read the link in my comment.

Comment: @Ace: also, you'll get a better answer with the smallest amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. Many users (including me) will simply not read so much code.

Comment: the "c#" in the title helps other people who are searching on google for that problem. if you want, you can change all my question-titles, they all have that information in it. like you did in some of you questions. also all the code IS necessary to understand the problem. I CAN'T simply post a code snipet cuz the problem can't be located in the part where it is occurring because it is a logical problem. and people who dont want to read the code should stay in just posting questions instead of answering it. - my opinion

Comment: @Picrofo if u want i could give you the vs project files of the client & server as an exe. actually i think this are two errors coming from one problem

Comment: I know a bit about the socket APIs and want to help. But I am staring at the code for 5min+ and about to give up.. more concise code please.

Comment: also if it helps, i was following this youtube tutorial for the socket code. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8Nlxtj0sV4
i'm pretty much shure that i've wrote the code exactly like in the video.

Comment: @Maxwell i will post a link with the project files in edit. give me some minutes

Comment: @Ace Thanks Ace, I almost solved the first problem. Now the server may disconnect normally. I'm tracing the second error! :)

Comment: glad to hear that. i would be glad if you can post the solution as answer with explanation for other people who have the same problem ^^

Comment: @Ace Sure thing! I'll post back the project files as soon as I solve the second error :)

Comment: @Ace Thanks Ace, I'm working on it! :)

Comment: @Ace I have a question. How are you calling sck.Dispose()? It says that it's inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: I'll be afk for some minutes ( it's 18:44 pm in germany ) so i dont know if you still will be online in an hour. well anyway thanks for your involvement :D

Comment: i dont know what you are meaning, i was calling it inside the client.cs Close() method ( server side ) and in the clients main class as it exits ( first i had the sck.Close(); and sck.Dispose(); inside an form_close event handler )

Comment: otherwhise as i said , i'm not familiar with socket programming , so i simply just followed the tutorial. maybe it's because the client.cs class and the Listener.cs class are not set to public class. idk.. :/

Comment: @Ace Okay, I do not want to delay you. I'll be trying to solve this problem til' you come back. Have a great day :)

Comment: @Ace I've successfully solved both problems. The first one took me some time though it was easy to detect. I'll post my answer in a minute :)

Comment: thats awesome. waiting to see what i've did wrong / forgot :D

Comment: @Ace I've posted my answer, sorry for taking too long! Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the first problem ( async error ) appears in the Listener.cs file in the try-catch. the messagebox in the catch section gives this text :
>
> > "IAsyncResult object was not returned from the corresponding
> >     asynchronous method. parameter : asyncResult"

In **Listener.cs - GameServer**, This error may be safely ignored. I believe that ignoring the error will not cause problems during starting / stopping the socket. The problem is that you forgot to add `Listening = false;` at the end of `Stop()` so that the application can call `Start()` once again to start the socket. Otherwise, the socket will never start if stopped.

**Example**

```
public void Stop()
{
     if (!Listening)
     {
          return;
     }

     s.Close();
     s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
     Listening = false; //Set Listening to False to start the socket again
}
```

Though setting `Listening = false;` will resolve restarting the socket, it will not stop you from getting the exception you mentioned above because the exception does not depend on `Listening`.

I've tried fixing this but it always told me that it was impossible to access the disposed object `s(socket)` so that I think that the exception is based on this line `s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);`.

The exception can be safely ignored anyways, I've ignored it and it worked perfectly. To ignore it, simply create a `try/catch` block getting the exception, if the exception message contained `asyncResult` then, ignore popping out a box with the exception.

**Example**

```
void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{

      try
      {

           Socket s = this.s.EndAccept(ar);
           if (SocketAccepted != null)
           {
                SocketAccepted(s);
           }
           this.s.BeginAccept(callback, null);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           if (!ex.Message.Contains("asyncResult")) //Proceed only if the exception does not contain asyncResult
           {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
      }
}
```

> it seems that it continuously receives blank data, so it outputs a blank message in the console/richTextBox

Yes, it will always receive a blank data since there's a connection. You can see this in the following screenshot

[image: Blank data sent from Picrofo Console]

To solve this, you'll first need to check that the returned string using `Encoding` from the `byte[] data` is not blank. Then, you can write a new line in the console/richtextbox

**Example**

<sup>In **Form1.cs - GameServer**</sup>

Replace `client_Received(Client sender, byte[] data)` with the following code

```
void client_Received(Client sender, byte[] data)
{
     if (Encoding.Default.GetString(data) != "") //Proceed only if data is not blank
     {
          Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
          {
               consoleWrite(DateTime.Now + "-" + sender.EndPoint + " :\n" + Encoding.Default.GetString(data) + "\n\n", Color.White); ;
            });
          }
     }
}
```

After applying the fix, here's the output

[image: No more blank data!]

There's another problem that you might have forgot to mention, under `Connections` tab, the list is never cleared even after the server disconnects. Simply call `dataGridViewConnections.Rows.Clear();` to clear the connections list when `ServerStop()` is called.

**Example**

<sup>**In Form1.cs - GameServer**</sup>

Replace `ServerStop()` with the following code

```
private void ServerStop()
{
     if (serverRunning)
     {
          consoleWrite("* Stopping server . . .\n", Color.Orange);
          l.Stop();
          serverRunning = false;
          consoleWrite("* Server stopped !\n\n", Color.Lime);
          dataGridViewConnections.Rows.Clear(); // Clear connections

     }
     else
     {
          consoleWrite("* ERROR: Server already stopped !\n\n", Color.Red);
     }
 }
```

That's all I could detect at the moment, I'll keep you updated if I find anything relevant.

Alternatively, you can find the project files that belongs to the namespace `GameServer` [here](https://gist.github.com/3969589)

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: I've uploaded the project files as well. You can have them [here](https://gist.github.com/3969589). Have a great day :)

Comment: wenn first of all: clearing the datagridview was the next task, i was concentratin on the socket logic XD i will clear the funktions later on.

second: thank you for having time to look at that stuff I've made. i was wondering if it really gets blank data after diskonnecting..., if it is so, isn't there the rist of overloading the bandwidth if i have 4 example more than 500 connections, and they all are sending blank data ( without connection ??? ) to the server, and it handles it.. ? can#t i make a pool for all the sockets i am creating, and detect if one of them disconnects and delete it ?

Comment: and 4 the async error: on the guys youtube channel who made that tutorial , there are two more videos called async anything blabla, is that the solution to follow that tutorials too ? i think async handlyng is a special way of doing something ( again, i dont have any idea of network programming )

Comment: for now i'll mark this as answer till any einstein comes and tells me that i can't ignore that error message ^^

Comment: @Ace Thanks a lot. I'm researching the problem. I've also noticed that the Game Client does not receive any messages in the rich text box. Is this a default behavior in your application?

Comment: solved, just a simple logic fail in the listener.cs ^^, the client is just a dummy. lateron i'll use that server for 3d3 application ( game ) clients, just added the richtextbox for dev. purposes ^^

Comment: @Ace Glad to hear it! I'll be looking forward to hearing from you about your incoming game. Have a great day :)

Comment: thank you for that commitment. you can mail me a link to your fb account if you want. maybe we could help out each other once ^^ x-s-z@hotmail.de

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18686/discussion-between-ace-and-picrofo-egy)